# How to decode the attachment file in [MIME] java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, decode, mime-message

I am unable to decode the attachment. It something like `=?utf-8?B?MS5qcGc=` which is encoded. I need to decode that attachment. 
The java code i am using to decode

```
private static String decodeName(String name) throws Exception {
  if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
   return "unknown";
  }
  String ret = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");

  // also check for a few other things in the string:
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=\\?utf-8\\?q\\?", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("\\?=", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=20", " ");

  return ret;
 }
```

Please help me out for decoding.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decode the attachment **name**, right?  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#encodefilename).